Compose lazy row items screen centralisation with rounded cornerrs
I have implemented a centrally located box with a lazy row with two items. The items are supposed to be just smaller than the screen and the starting position needs to be horizontally centred. I am monitoring the scrollState to run a page indicator below the lazy row.
Currently the scrollstate index works but the item doesnt start centred in the screen. If I reduce the space between the scrollstate index stops working as I believe all items are  "showing". The roundedCornerShape is not implementing on the boxes on screen.
 Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .align(Alignment.TopCenter)
            .padding(top = 142.dp),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,

            
    ) {


        LazyRow(
            state = scrollState,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(100.dp),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 30.dp)



        ) {
            item {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(screenWidth - 52.dp)
                        .height(406.dp)
                        .background(ChatTextFieldBG)
                        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))


                ) {
                    //  todo:
                }
            }
            item {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(screenWidth - 52.dp)
                        .height(406.dp)
                        .background(ChatTextFieldBG)
                        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))


                ) {
                    // todo:
                }
            }
        }
    }

